# display sparse quiver arrows using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient

When illustrating gradients using quiver on images, arrows are very dense. How would I show the general trend instead of every individual arrow?

For example, showing the quiver arrows for the gradient in this image:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = Image.open('test.png')
array = np.array(image)
array = array[:,:,1]
array = array.astype(float)
dy, dx = np.gradient(array)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(array)
plt.quiver(dx, -dy)
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

whereas I would like the arrows to be larger and sparser, something like this:
[image]

adding

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[0:50:5, 0:50:5]
plt.quiver(X, Y, dx[::5, ::5], -dy[::5, ::5])
```

produces strange results

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `quiver` plot has a paramter `scale`. From [♦the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html):

> scale: [ None | float ]
>   Data units per arrow length unit, e.g., m/s per plot width; a smaller scale parameter makes the arrow longer. If None, a simple autoscaling algorithm is used, based on the average vector length and the number of vectors.

Setting this scale to a reasonable value, also lets the plot appear nicer. Also check the other parameters, such as `scale_units` and `units`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = lambda x,y, x0,y0, sig: np.exp((-(x-x0)**2- (y-y0)**2)/sig**2)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(50), np.arange(50))
array = f(X,Y, 24,24,7.)

dy, dx = np.gradient(array)

n = 3
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
plt.imshow(array)
plt.quiver(X[::n,::n],Y[::n,::n],dx[::n,::n], -dy[::n,::n], 
           np.sqrt(dx[::n,::n]**2+dy[::n,::n]**2),
           units="xy", scale=0.04, cmap="Reds")
plt.show()
```